# Get numerical values from input fields and use them to calculate the surface area of a trapezoid

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I will be thankful if someone help me understand what I am doing wrong. I am trying to calculate the surface area of a trapezoid by obtaining values from input fields. When I press the "Calculate S" button I get a "Nan" as an answer.
This is the major part of the HTML code:

```
    <form method="post">
    <label for="a">a</label>
    <input type="text" id="a"/> <br/>
    <label for="b">b</label>
    <input type="text" id="b"/> <br/>
    <label for="h">h</label>
    <input type="text" id="h"/> <br/>
    <button onclick="alert(S)">Calculate S</button>
    </form>
```

And this is the script I am using to obtain the values and calculate the surface:

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
            var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("a"), 10);
            var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("b"), 10);
            var h=parseInt(document.getElementById("h"), 10);
            var S=parseInt(((a+b)/2)*h, 10);
        </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value out of each input, not just the input, like this:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value, 10);
        var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value, 10);
        var h=parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value, 10);
        var S=((a+b)/2)*h;
    </script>
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the problem. That said, the code needs to be in a function called by the button, otherwise it'll just take the default values (empty strings here) and parse them (NaN) to give the result NaN.

Comment: @Kolink, good point, too many problems in one question for me.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `.value` property on the input elements to get their contents. then call `parseInt` on *that* to get a number.
2. No need to `parseInt` the result too.
   `var S = ((a + b) / 2) * h;`
3. Wrap the code in a callable function if you want it executed on button click (what you have now will execute when the code been parsed by your browser).

Example found here: http://jsfiddle.net/bpwEh/

Updated code:

```
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script>
        function calc(){
            var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value, 10);
            var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value, 10);
            var h=parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value, 10);
            return ((a+b)/2)*h, 10;
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="a">a</label>
        <input type="text" id="a"/> <br/>
        <label for="b">b</label>
        <input type="text" id="b"/> <br/>
        <label for="h">h</label>
        <input type="text" id="h"/> <br/>
        <button onclick="alert(calc()); return false;">Calculate S</button>
    </form>
</body>
```